# Python iterate through a list of class objects and extract a value

Tags: python

Hello I am having some trouble with trying to iterate through a list of classes in order to print out a particular value that thet instance of that class holds.My program compiles but it does not print any thing out, I have also tried having "player.player in playerlist" in the for loop but I also got the same result.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My main function

```
class main:

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:

        print("Please Select An Option Below:")
        print("1 - Create Player:")
        print("2 - List Players:")
        print("3 - Create Team:")
        print("4 - Sell Player:")
        print("5 - Buy Player:")
        x = raw_input("Please select a option: \n")

        playerList = []

        if(x == '1'):

            import Player
            p1 = Player.player()
            pname = raw_input("Please Enter A Player Name \n")
            page = raw_input("Please Enter A Player Age \n")
            pwage = raw_input("Please Enter A Player Wage \n")
            pteam = raw_input("Please Enter A Player Team \n")
            p1.pname = pname
            p1.page = page
            p1.pwage = pwage
            p1.pteam = pteam
            playerList.append(p1)
            continue

        if(x == '2'):
            for p1 in playerList:
                print(p1.pname)
            continue
```

My player class

```
class player(object):

    @property
    def pname(self):
        return self.pname

    @pname.setter
    def pname (self, value):
        pass

    @property
    def page(self):
        return self.page

    @page.setter
    def page (self, value):
        pass

    @property
    def pwage(self):
        return self.pwage

    @pwage.setter
    def pwage(self, value):
        pass

    @property
    def pteam(self):
        return self.pteam

    @pteam.setter
    def pteam(self, value):
        pass
```

----update-----

```
class main:

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        while True:

            print("Please Select An Option Below:")
            print("1 - Create Player:")
            print("2 - List Players:")
            print("3 - Create Team:")
            print("4 - Sell Player:")
            print("5 - Buy Player:")
            x = raw_input("Please select a option: \n")

            playerList = []

            if(x == '1'):

                import Player
                nplayer = Player.player()
                nplayer.set_name(raw_input("test\n"))
                playerList.append(nplayer)
                continue

            if(x == '2'):
                 for player in playerList:
                     print(player.get_name)
                 continue

class player(object):

    __name = ""

    @property
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

Comment: please fix your indentation. Because it seems you're not running anything at the global scope because of `class main:`

Comment: Your setters are empty. Is this normal?

Comment: Every time you display your menu, you initialize playerList to an empty list.  You therefore discard any added players before you could possibly print them out.

Comment: Thank you,somehow I failed to spot that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `p1.pname = pname`the setter is called. However, you don't do anything in the setter. So when the getter is called later, it doesn't have anything to return.

For getters and setters to work in python, you need to do something like this:

```
class player(object):
    @property
    def pname(self):
        return self._pname

    @pname.setter
    def pname (self, value):
        self._pname = value
```

Comment: Hello many thanks for your reply,I have updated my code to reflect the changes you suggested (see the updated code in the first post)I can successfully get and set a value using the setter/getter,but I still cannot get a "for loop"it outputting a specific attribute of a class (in this case player name)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to those who helped it my problem was caused by not setting up the setter/getter properly as told above and me having my array in the display menu option causing it to send the instance of the class to another list.

```
class main:

if __name__ == '__main__':

    playerList = [] 

    while True:

        print("Please Select An Option Below:")
        print("1 - Create Player:")
        print("2 - List Players:")
        print("3 - Create Team:")
        print("4 - Sell Player:")
        print("5 - Buy Player:")
        x = raw_input("Please select a option: \n")

        if(x == '1'):

            import Player
            nplayer = Player.player()
            nplayer.set_name(raw_input("Please Enter A Name\n"))
            playerList.append(nplayer)
            continue

        if(x == '2'):
             for nplayer in playerList:
                 print(nplayer.get_name)
             continue

class player(object):

__name = ""

@property
def get_name(self):
    return self.__name

def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name
```